# Call FluentPDO once

Tags: php, pdo

I am using slim framework together with [FluentPDO](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo) query builder and this is what I'm currently doing:

```
$app->get('/song/remove/:songID', function($songID) use($app) {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=songs", "root");
    $fpdo = new FluentPDO($pdo);
    $query = $fpdo->deleteFrom('songlist')->where('songID', $songID)->execute();
    $app->flash('msg', 'Song ID '.$songID.' removed.');
    $app->redirect('/');

});

$app->get('/song/view/:songID', function($songID) use($app) {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=songs", "root");
    $fpdo = new FluentPDO($pdo);

    $song = $fpdo->from('songlist')->where('songID', $songID);
    $app->render('view-song.html', [
        'song' => $song //pass variable to template
    ]);
});
```

As you can see, I am calling this code in every function:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=songs", "root");
$fpdo = new FluentPDO($pdo);
```

What I wanted to do is to just call it once, so that if I will change something in my database, I'll only change a single line. How can I accomplish that? THank you.

Comment: You should either call it once on your script (when it starts?) and set $fpdo as a global variable, or if it fits your design better, set it as a variable of `$app`.

Comment: How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project structure, the logic is to create a bootstrap or configuration file that will contains all your project constants (database connection, paths ...) that will be loaded by default in your entire application.

this video by *codeschool* may help setting up one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFeWo1cqxnM

here is a project skeleton that you may consider:
https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton

*Hope it helps*